# Applying logistic regression to simple dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataset, logistic-regression

I have trying to apply logistic regression or any other of ML algorithm to this simple data set but I have failed miserably and got many error. I am tr

```
 dim(data)
 [1] 11580    12

 head(data)
 ReturnJan   ReturnFeb   ReturnMar   ReturnApr    ReturnMay  ReturnJune
  1  0.08067797  0.06625000  0.03294118  0.18309859  0.130333952 -0.01764234
  2 -0.01067989  0.10211539  0.14549595 -0.08442804 -0.327300392 -0.35926605
  3  0.04774193  0.03598972  0.03970223 -0.16235294 -0.147426982  0.04858934
  4 -0.07404022 -0.04816956  0.01821862 -0.02467917 -0.006036217 -0.02530364
  5 -0.03104575 -0.21267723  0.09147609  0.18933823 -0.153846154 -0.10611511
  6  0.57980016  0.33225225 -0.40546095 -0.06000000  0.060732113 -0.21536106
```

## And the 12th column the one I am trying to predict looks like this

```
      PositiveDec
      0
      0
      0
      1
      1
      1
```

Here is my attempt

```
new.data <- data[,-12] #Remove labels' column

index <- sample(1:nrow(new.data), size = 0.8*nrow(new.data))#Split data

train.data <- new.data[index,]

test.data <- new.data[-index,]

fit.glm <- glm(data[,12]~.,data = data, family = "binomial")
```

Comment: Can you post the "many errors" you received by running your code?

Comment: There is it `Error in model.frame.default(formula = data$PositiveDec ~ ., data = train.data,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'ReturnJan')`

Comment: Don't remove the outcome column. `data$PositiveDec=factor(data$PositiveDec); train.data=data[index,]; fit.glm = glm(PositiveDec ~ ., data = train.data, family=binomial)`.

Comment: @eipi10 since it's the column we are trying to predict I thought we had to remove it from our model

Comment: No. With `glm` use a single data frame and put the outcome column on the left side of the formula.

Comment: Right that makes sense just tried it and it works thanks

Comment: That makes sense It works perfectly thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting there, but have several syntactic errors and, as pointed out in comments, need to leave your outcome variable in.  This should work:

```
index <- sample(1:nrow(data), size = 0.8 * nrow(data))
train.data <- data[index, ]
fit.glm <- glm(PositiveDec ~ ., data = train.data, family = "binomial")
```